# Bring all values in an array closer together

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I need to do is "crush" the values in l1 by some percentage so they are closer together such that perhaps if an array l1 were ...

```
l1 =[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
```

Then l2 *could be...*

```
l2 = [12.5, 25.0, 37.5, 50.0, 62.5, 45.0, 52.5, 60.0, 67.5, 75.0]
```

That can be done on a simple script such as...

```
for i in l1:
    if i <= 50:
        i = (i*1.25)
        l2.append(i)
        print(i)
    elif i >= 50:
        i = (i*0.75)
        l2.append(i)

print (l2)
```

So that's to indicate I need to bring all the items closer together - ideally by some percentile (printed). The problem occurs when you have a list like this...

```
l1 =[4,2,3,4,3,6,4,8.6,10,7,12,4,14,15,26,14,15,16,10]
```

What I need to then do is bring all the items together discretely (so by some percentage) but in a loop. I need to "condense" or "crush" the values of the array, reduce the range between each number from smallest to biggest and biggest to smallest (closer to the median). I can't just divide by the whole list since the ranges remain the same.

I thought one way to approach this (what I'm working on now) would be to (a) find the median of l1, (b) start from the smallest and biggest item in l1, increase that item by 10% of it's value or decrease it by 10% of its value (in the case of the biggest item), then work to the second smallest and biggest items in the same loop (to avoid the script going over the same 'smaller variable' twice).

This would mean listing the values from biggest to smallest whilst maintaining their positions in the array (which are important), then searching through that list and making the changes for each corresponding value to the array l1.

For the attention of the proposed solution... One iteration of...

```
import statistics
a = [4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1, 31, 321]
input_scope = 1.1

def scouter (input_list, scope):
    mean = statistics.mean(input_list)
    searchpositions = []
    for x, i in enumerate(input_list):
            print (x, i)
            if i == max(input_list) or i == min(input_list):
                searchpositions.append(x)

    for i in searchpositions:
        input_list[i] = [(input_list[i] - mean) / scope + mean]
    return (input_list)
print(scouter((a), input_scope))
```

Gives me what I need, sort of...

```
[4, 3, 3, 4, 5, [5.13636363636364], 31, [296.0454545454545]]
```

Output is lists in lists! Is there an easy way to eliminate this by re-writing the function?

Comment: I don't understand how you compute `l2` from `l1` above. For example, why does `2` remain `2`?

Comment: You may get an answer more easily if you clarify what properties a good solution needs to have. For example, what's wrong with this simpler soluton: `l2 = [x * 0.01 for x in l1]`?

Comment: If your application has a bug, you may want to fix the bug instead of trying to work around the input values.

Comment: The bug is caused by the input values. To be frank this is inevitable to happen. Updated the example.

Comment: For your solution if I apply it to the whole list the range between the numbers doesn't change (so it doesn't work around the issue). If I apply it procedurally I risk the largest starting numbers becoming smaller than other numbers: whatever position of the biggest/smallest number is it must *stay* the position of the biggest/smallest number.

Comment: In your first example, is it really ok to change [..., 50, 60, ...] to [..., 62.5, 45.0, ...]?

Comment: Ah. No it isn't (which I suppose is part of the problem). Scratching my head!

Comment: What is the desired output for the second example?

Comment: Do they really need to get closer to the median, or would closer to the mean also be ok?

Comment: Getting closer to the mean would be OK. Possibly a better idea. The desired output for the second example is going to be the output of the formula, I wouldn't be able to calculate it by hand.

Comment: @mmacheerpuppy Better use `@name` when you respond so people get notified and don't miss your response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just scale towards the median?

```
>>> l1 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

>>> import statistics
>>> median = statistics.median(l1)
>>> [(x - median) / 10 + median for x in l1]
[50.5, 51.5, 52.5, 53.5, 54.5, 55.5, 56.5, 57.5, 58.5, 59.5]
```

Comment: Haven't even got this module installed. Let me see how this copes with the data.

Comment: @mmacheerpuppy It was introduced in Python 3.4, so maybe time to update? :-). Or just do it yourself, see [the source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/statistics.py#l337). Or if you can use the mean instead of the median, that's of course even simpler.

Comment: Thanks for this! Works for some data-sets but not bigger more complex data sets (what you end up with is every number eventually being made equal to the mean/median. Is there a way to target only the biggest/smallest numbers in the array?

Comment: @mmacheerpuppy There surely is a way. But please give an example of such a case where every number becomes the mean/median.

Comment: Wrote my function to get the job done with your advice! But this gives me lists in lists! :( I've added what I've done to the main body for your perusal with the output. Can you advise what I've done wrong: is there a way to make a function to do this without creating a list in a list or will I have to flatten that list?

Comment: @mmacheerpuppy Uuh... well... it's a list because you explicitly make it a list. No idea why you're doing that.

Comment: Yep just noticed why that was happening my mistake! That's what happens when you spend a full day coding! Time for bed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not find the lowest number in your list and divide the whole list by that number? Or even any number that you want.

```
num = percentage/100 # gets you a decimal
l2 = [x*num for x in l1]
```

Use `min()` to find the lowest number of the list if you want to go that way.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I need to creep inwards either from biggest and smallest towards the median or start from the median and creep outwards. I figured it would be easier to do the former. I have updated the post to better illustrate.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late, but I know exactly what you need and I have the solution I used also for myself. I came up with this solution:

For every number **n** in the set, you get a new number **x** which is closer to the **mean** of the set, by this formula:

```
x = mean + factor * (n - mean)
```

**Factor** ranges from 0 to 1 and represents how much the numbers need to grow or shrink towards the average. 0 = all numbers become the average, 1 = all numbers remain the same. Tweak to your own needs.

The mean of the set is obviously the sum of every number in the set divided by the length of the set.

Hope this helps to whoever lands here in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on ndrqu's answer:

```
import statistics as stats
l1_mean = stats.mean(l1)
factor = 0.99
l2 = []
for i in range(len(l1)):
    l2.append(l1_mean + factor * (l1[i] - l1_mean))
```

This will turn

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

into

```
l2 = [1.02,2.01,3.00,3.99,4.98]
```